# Well pump issues

Tags: plumbing, well-pump

Help.. we just installed a new pressure tank, and pressure switch.. we got everything working except now the pressure gauge always reads 50psi.. dies not move when running water in the house.  Also the pressure is very low especially in the upstairs shower.. we read how to adjust the pressure but with the gauge always reading 50 psi idk what we are doing... do the gauges also go bad or is it reading presssure from the tank?  So confused!

Comment: do you realize that we have no idea how your system is set up .... pretend that we are not standing next to you and update your question

Comment: I agree a new pressure tank and or switch is not helpful without more information,

Comment: What tank (size, mfg, size)? What switch? How are they connected? What pump? What is the distance between the tank and the pump. Where is the system located, a pump house or in the basement. There are too many variables to give you proper (and potentially helpful) insights.

Comment: It is a 20 gallon tank, American grandby 30-50 pressure switch and a Gould’s deep well submersible pump. The well is 65-70 ft deep , from the wall to inside the basement is less than 10 ft... the system is located in the basement.

Answer (score 1):

Some mistakes I've made:

- Did an initial test of plumbing changes by cracking a valve open(so if there's a leak it's not a big one...) then forgetting to finish opening it.  Check that all the valves that should be open are actually fully open.
- Banging things about loosened enough crud that the aeration screens and shower heads are filled with crud.  Take them apart, clean and put back together.

May have gotten a bad gauge.  To test the gauge:

Turn off power to the pump.  Open a tap fairly low down in the house.  (Outside tap works well) As the pressure tank drains, you should see the gauge go down.  If it eventually gets down to zero or nearby, then the gauge is working.  May not be accurate.

If the gauge still reads something significant after the water has stopped running, then the gauge is broken.  Replace it.  Easy to do.  You will need a wrench and teflon tape.

Once you have a good gauge, try this:  Run a garden hose to about the same height as the problem tap upstairs.  Carrying the end up a ladder is one easy way.  If you get good flow through the garden hose but still have problems with the upstairs tap, then you have a problem with the tap or the plumbing between.

You get about 2 feet elevation per psi.  If your pressure tank is in the basement, and then the upstairs tap is about 20 feet up.  50 psi in the basement will be about 45 on the main floor, and 40 upstairs.

This should be enough to get reasonable flow.

---

Here the usual pressure switch has two adjustments:  The high pressure, and the differential.  One sets the cut off when the pump is charging the tank, the differential sets how much lower the cut in pressure is.  It's not strictly linear.  Adjust the high pressure first, then the differential.  Instructions are usually on a label under the cover.

Note:  The contacts are live.  Either turn off the power before going in with metal tools, or do the adjustments with a plastic handled nut driver.

A large differential means the well isn't turning on and off as often -- better for both well and pump.  A small differential is less nuisance in the house.  We compromised at 70 psi for the high, and a 12 pound differential.